# Can an array of shorts be passed into a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I have written a CUDA kernel and when I copy of an array of shorts to device memory and then pass it to the kernel it doesn't work. The simplified code below expresses my issue.

```
KernelCaller()
{
    const int size = 1;
    short hostArray[size]{41};
    short* devPointer;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&devicePointer, size * sizeof(short));
    cudaMemcpy(devPointer, hostArray, size * sizeof(short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaKernel<<<1,1>>>(devPointer);

}

__global__
void cudaKernel(short* arr)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    short val = arr[idx];
}
```

At this point the value of `val` is 1063714857 and what I want it to be is 41.
I assume the issue is 41 in hex is 0x29 and the value I have is 0x3F670029 so it looks like it read too many bytes cause the 0x29 is at the beginning. When I switch to an array of floats it works perfectly, but I was trying to save memory. Does CUDA not allow an array of shorts?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TQa09ggt -- it most certainly can. If the code at the pastebin link fails, your CUDA installation is probably broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented your code and getting the output as expected.

Here's the code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
__global__ void cudaKernel(short* arr)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    short val = arr[idx];
    # if __CUDA_ARCH__>=200
        printf("Inside kernel %d\n",val);
    #endif
    arr[idx] = val;
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 1;
    short hostArray[size]{41};
    printf("Before kernel call %d\n",hostArray[0]);
    short *devPointer;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&devPointer, size * sizeof(short));
    cudaMemcpy(devPointer, hostArray, size * sizeof(short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaKernel<<<1,1>>>(devPointer);
    cudaMemcpy(hostArray, devPointer, size * sizeof(short), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("After kernel call %d\n",hostArray[0]);
    cudaFree(devPointer);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
Before kernel call 41
Inside kernel 41
After kernel call 41
```

So, yes we can pass array of shorts into a CUDA kernel.